# Powershell: Capture process id of a background job

Tags: powershell

I want to start a background job and capture it's process id into a .pid file. I was able to do it with the Start-Process as follows:

```
Start-Process C:\process.bat -passthru | foreach { $_.Id } > start.pid
```

Now, I want to wrap Start-Process with Start-Job, to run it in the background, like this:

```
$command = "Start-Process C:\process.bat -passthru | foreach { $_.Id }"
$scriptblock = [Scriptblock]::Create($command)
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
```

Unfortunatelly, this doesn't work and Receive-Job gives me the following error:

```
The term '.Id' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.Id:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
+ PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Looks like it's something wrong with the $_ variable. Maybe it gets overwritten by the Start-Job.

Any clues greatly welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the variable is being expanded when using double quotes. If you want to keep the $_, then you need to use single quotes.

```
$command = 'Start-Process C:\process.bat -passthru | foreach { $_.Id }'
$scriptblock = [Scriptblock]::Create($command)
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
```

Comment: alternatively you can escape it, e.g. if you wanted to use expansion for some parts of the string - like ``$command = "Start-Process c:\$filename.bat -passthru | foreach { `$_.Id }"``

Comment: (also in this case you could simply do ``$command = "Start-Process c:\process.bat -PassThru | select Id"``)