# How can I tell what processes are started by a Start-Job command?

Tags: powershell, process, jobs, powershell-jobs

I have (inherited) a PowerShell script that calls other PowerShell scripts by invoking them with a `Start-Job` cmdlet and the `-FilePath` parameter. For example, I have a script that does nothing:

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 86400
```

Which I can invoke via a job:

```
PS> Start-Job -Name "Test Job" -FilePath ".\Wait-AllDay.ps1"

Id Name     PSJobTypeName State   HasMoreData Location  Command                        
-- ----     ------------- -----   ----------- --------  -------                        
2  Test Job BackgroundJob Running True        localhost Start-Sleep...

PS> Get-Job -Id 2

State         : Running
HasMoreData   : True
StatusMessage : 
Location      : localhost
Command       : Start-Sleep -Seconds (60*60*24)
JobStateInfo  : Running
Finished      : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
InstanceId    : 0c0e2c32-cbc5-4d70-b7cb-28771626cf20
Id            : 2
Name          : Test Job
ChildJobs     : {Job3}
PSBeginTime   : 25/01/2016 15:06:22
PSEndTime     : 
PSJobTypeName : BackgroundJob
```

Is there any easy & reliable way to find out what process is associated with this job (which I believe will be an additional **powershell.exe**)? Obviously this is easy in testing with just one job, but on a server I may have many of these running concurrently.

### Why do I want to do/know this?

I'm in a new role, working on a server which has multiple scheduled tasks running a variety of scripts. Some of these call other scripts which my predecessor chose to invoke using Start-Job, possibly because they can be long running (multiple hours) and wanted them to work in parallel. Occasionally they seem to get stuck and I'd like to kill them, but don't want to risk stopping something that is still healthy.

Having started down this path, it is probably more plain curiosity as to how to match up jobs and processes, since I'll most likely start rewriting some of these scripts in the near future.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308385/how-to-get-process-id-of-a-running-process-as-shown-in-task-manager. If the job was completed you can you `Receive-Job` to see what the PID _was_. Not useful if you want to know it ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was reasonably _au-fait_ with jobs, but this one has me stumped. I can get reasonably close by getting the PID of the parent process and then finding all child processes with WMI, but I can't seem to spot a property that ties the two together for certain.

Comment: [Perhaps related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25764631/1630171).

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the answer to "can I tell which process matches up with each job" is **no**.

However, it seems that there are some clues as to which processes are the ones that match up with the job(s).

1. They have a command line such as:

   `"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Version 4.0 -s -NoLogo -NoProfile`
2. They are child processes of either another **powershell.exe** or **powershell_ise.exe** process, depending on how they are invoked. If the parent process is called by task manager or other scheduling agent, then the odds are that there will be a script name in the process command line, which may help. In my case this wasn't too much of a help as each scheduled task was spawning ~4 powershell.exe background processes.
3. If you have details of when each job was started (easy if you can run the `Get-Job` cmdlet to return the job details), you might be able to match up jobs to processes based on timestamps, but even in simple tests there wasn't an *exact* match; the job and process were 1-2 seconds apart in starting.

Other than that, I couldn't find any useful way to identify the actual processes linked to each job.

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question he asked. I'm going to post my code of trying to do this and report whether or not I get this working

Answer (score 3):

Using the `*-Job` cmdlets might be a better approach than fiddling with the actual processes. Use [`Get-Job`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849693.aspx) to list existing jobs:

```
PS C:\> Get-Job

Id   Name    PSJobTypeName   State       HasMoreData   Location      Command
--   ----    -------------   -----       -----------   --------      -------
2    Job2    BackgroundJob   Running     False         localhost     Do-Some
4    Job4    BackgroundJob   Completed   True          localhost     Get-Other
```

The `Command` property holds the content of the scriptblock the job is/was running.

```
(Get-Job -Id 2).Command
```

The `State` property shows the current state of the job (running, completed, failed, blocked, ...). The `HasMoreData` property indcates whether the job has output that you can fetch via [`Receive-Job`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849718.aspx).

```
Receive-Job -Id 4
```

Jobs can be stopped via [`Stop-Job`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849730.aspx), and [`Remove-Job`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849742.aspx) removes terminated jobs from the job list.

See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288.aspx) for further information about background jobs.

Comment: Just what I was about to do... Given the comments this is really what the op is looking for.

Comment: Can I use this to see jobs started by another user? I reckon I can use this answer if I start PowerShell running as another user (i.e. the account under which the scheduled task runs) but was wondering if I could short-cut that additional logon...

Comment: No. You can only see jobs started from your current PowerShell console. If you need to look at things started by other users you'll want to use `Get-Process`. I don't think you'll have job information available in that scenario.

Comment: Which almost brings me back to my first question. Almost. As far as I have been able to make out so far, multiple `Start-Job` cmdlets might invoke multiple PowerShell processes, and once someone kicks off a bunch of these, I'm left guessing which powershell.exe is doing what.